# How can I make list item spacing more acceptable in html/css email for all viewers?

Tags: html, css, email, html-lists

First of all, this is for email, so I can't put css in the head, only in the table, td, ul, etc.

I'll paste my code snippet and screenshots of what it looks like in IE, Firefox, and MS Outlook.

```
            <html>
             <head>
             </head>
             <body>
              <table cellpadding="5" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#333; border-left: solid 1px #e9e9e9; border: thin groove #CCCCCC">
                 <tr bgcolor=#FF8100 valign="top">
                   <td style="border-bottom-style: groove; border-bottom-width: thin"><strong>To Do</strong></td>
                   <td style="border-bottom-style: groove; border-bottom-width: thin"><strong>Document</strong></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr bgcolor=#FFCA99 valign="top">
                   <td>Review
                   </td>
                   <td> 
                     <ul style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;">
                      <li>Good Faith Estimate - outlines all the fees and costs associated with your loan</li>
                      <li>Uniform Residential Loan Application (If your property is in New York, Ohio or Mississippi, please sign this form and upload it to My Status or fax it back to me at @AGENT.FAX.)</li>
                     </ul>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                </table>
               </body>
              </html>
```

It looks great in IE, but in Firefox there's a huge margin, and in Outlook, only a tiny part of the bullet is showing.

IE:

[image: IE View]

Firefox:

[image: FF View]

Outlook:

[image: Outlook View]

I have to assume the audience is likely to use all of these options to view this email, so how can I make it look good universally?   I tried putting the padding in the ul style, I tried making a bullet image, using that as the li background image, and giving ul no style... that didn't work either.  Everything I try looks horrible on at least 2 out of the 3 email views.

I'd really appreciate the help!

(Gmail is the strictest on what css will be interpreted, so I have to follow their rules.  Those can be found here ->  http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/   You can see that Gmail on Android won't allow list-style-x, so I can't use any of them.  I can only use the ones with all green check marks.)

Thanks!
-Holly

Comment: I'll suggest you to change it inline using `firebug`.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann Since I kept the code so simple, the html is literally that, with just the html and body open and close tags... so it doesn't really tell me anything.  Or if there are features of firebug that can help me add the exact right thing to answer my question, let me know?  Thanks! -Holly

Comment: Use normalize.css to get a starting point that is more reasonably similar between browsers!  That's my very late-to-the-game advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply resetting the padding/margins on the ul and li went pretty far!  Thanks @keeg!

With this code:

```
      <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
      <table cellpadding="5" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#333; border-left: solid 1px #e9e9e9; border: thin groove #CCCCCC">
         <tr bgcolor=#FF8100 valign="top">
           <td style="border-bottom-style: groove; border-bottom-width: thin"><strong>To Do</strong></td>
           <td style="border-bottom-style: groove; border-bottom-width: thin"><strong>Document</strong></td>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor=#FFCA99 valign="top">
           <td>Review
           </td>
           <td style="padding-left:25px;"> 
             <ul style="padding:0px;margin:0;">
              <li style="padding:0px;margin:0;">Good Faith Estimate - outlines all the fees and costs associated with your loan</li>
              <li style="padding:0px;margin:0;">Uniform Residential Loan Application (If your property is in New York, Ohio or Mississippi, please sign this form and upload it to My Status or fax it back to me at @AGENT.FAX.)</li>
             </ul>
           </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
       </body>
   </html>
```

It looks like this in IE, Firefox, and Outlook (in that order from top to bottom), which isn't perfect because of Outlook's view of it, but much more acceptable:

[image: With resetting]

Answer (score 1):

Put the padding on the td, not the ul, you probably need to reset the styles of ul and li elements too

```
<html>
         <head>
         </head>
         <body>
          <table cellpadding="5" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#333; border-left: solid 1px #e9e9e9; border: thin groove #CCCCCC">
             <tr bgcolor=#FF8100 valign="top">
               <td style="border-bottom-style: groove; border-bottom-width: thin"><strong>To Do</strong></td>
               <td style="border-bottom-style: groove; border-bottom-width: thin"><strong>Document</strong></td>
             </tr>
             <tr bgcolor=#FFCA99 valign="top">
               <td>Review
               </td>
               <td style="padding-left:15px;"> 
                 <ul style="padding:0px;margin:0;">
                  <li>Good Faith Estimate - outlines all the fees and costs associated with your loan</li>
                  <li>Uniform Residential Loan Application (If your property is in New York, Ohio or Mississippi, please sign this form and upload it to My Status or fax it back to me at @AGENT.FAX.)</li>
                 </ul>
               </td>
             </tr>
            </table>
           </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: That didn't work. :(   It looks exactly like my 3 screenshots except more to the left, so in Outlook the bullets don't appear in view.

I can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: and you have both `<ul style="padding:0px;margin:0;">` and maybe add `<li style="padding:0px;margin:0;">` to all your li elements (though really you should just reset all that stuff in the css)

Comment: Actually adding the li style makes it look perfect in FF and IE, just doesn't let them appear in Outlook.  At least that is 1/3rd better than I was before! :)   Thanks, I'll look into why I need to reset for Outlook and I'll try that next!  -Holly

Comment: After trying different reset snippets, the best thing was actually exactly what you had, with the li style added, and td margin of 25 instead of 15.   It actually looks good in all of them now instead of having a huge difference in a gap!  I'm going with this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Padding is not supported in all email clients. 
To insure correct spacing between list items, don't make it a list.
Sorry.

```
<tr>
<td width="10">&bull;</td><td width="5" style="font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td><td... content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="10" height="5" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td> etc...
```

empty TDs don't display in IE, TDs without a font-size render as default (say 12px) size in IE and many, many more things like this. Declaring an empty row with height and styling of font-size and line-height on the empty table cells fixes the space between items.

Comment: mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 1px <--- add that mso rule to make it work better on outlook 2013.. It has to go directly before the line height rule, because Microsoft